# Can I change where the root directory of a local HTML project is?

Tags: html

On a web server (including localhost), having a link to `/` or a stylesheet at `/style/myapp.css` works fine. However, when the project is local (that is, on a `file://` URL), a link to `/` leads to the file system root. Is there any way to specify to the browser where the root of a local project is?

Comment: In general you should do local development with a server, not with files

Comment: I agree with Andy, though the [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this on your index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('a').click(function() {
        document.location = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment above, but if you are using Windows, you can use something like Wampserver: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

I personally recommend it because it's very simple to use, and it will give you a web server with MySQL and PHP. Your benefit is you will be able to duplicate the same environment locally that you have on your server.

You can set your local folder to anywhere you prefer and check it from web browser at http://localhost

Hope that helps. Try and duplicate both environments so can always work with your creations. If you install Wamp and you cant access it via http://localhost, then you probably have a firewall issue, so you need to investigate how to open up port 80.

That sounds like it will solve your issue also.

http://localhost/style/myapp.css would refer to "/style/myapp.css".

If you were hosting your Wamp server from c:\wamp64\www then the location "/style/myapp.css" would be referring to C:\wamp64\www\style\myapp.css

-Adam